# I am rendering in lower resolution, but background is not scaling down to match when rendered

Tags: rendering, video

I am trying to make a scene with camera math (using Blender v2.91.0).
When I test-rendered the scene, it took all day to render, even though it is a very simple scene so far (my computer is not very fast).
So I would very much like to reduce the render-resolution to speed the rendering.

But when I set set the Resolution to 50% (or something else smaller then 100%) it only scales the rendered elements down, the background image it put in full size cropped (It correct in the viewport and when I render in 100% resolution).

I have tried all I can think of, to correct this: "Frame Method: Stretch", "Frame Method: Fit", "Proxy Render Size 50%"

And I have spend a long time trying to Google solution, but with no luck.

I guess, it is a simple thing, I have missed, and I hope someone here can help me.

***The first picture is how it is supposed to be (screen dump from viewport).***
***The second picture is how it looks rendered in 50% resolution :(***
[image: Correct scale]

[image: Wrong Scale]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, blender will not automatically resize the image when you render at 50%. It will only render 50% percent of the pixels around the center of the image (Think of the percentage not as a resize, but as a crop).

If you want to resize use a scale node, set it to render size and Fit, so that the image is rescaled using the output resolution.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick :)

I do find that strange though. That the 3d elements are resized matching the 50% resolution, but the background cropped instead (as seen on the pictures are the 3D-part higher that the house in the background, in viewport inside Blender (and when rendered in 100%), but when rendered in 50% the 3D-part is barely higher than the gate in the background.

But anyways, inserting the scale node works, and I am happy now :)